# How to log in to a hacked Google account without phone?

Tags: google-account, lost-phone

I'm trying to log into my Google account, and it won't let me get past the verification steps because I don't know what they changed the password to, and obviously I no longer have access to the number because they stole the phone.

Comment: This is a Google-specific problem, and only tangentially Android-related.

Answer (score 3):

There are some solutions that [Google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7682439?hl=en) suggests, you should try them first.

> **Forgot your password**
>
> 1. Follow the steps to [recover your Google Account or Gmail](https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery?ec=ar_c).
>
>    - You'll be asked some questions to confirm it's your account. Answer the questions as best as you can.
>    - If you have trouble, try the [tips to complete account recovery steps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7299973).
> 2. Reset your password when prompted. Choose a strong password that you haven't already used with this account. [Learn how to create a strong password.](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32040)
>
> **Forgot the email address you use to sign in**
>
> 1. To find your username, [follow these steps](https://accounts.google.com/signin/usernamerecovery?ec=ur_c). You need to know:
>
>    - A phone number or the recovery email address for the account.
>    - The full name on your account.
> 2. Follow the instructions to confirm it’s your account.
> 3. You’ll find a list of usernames that match your account.
>
> **Someone else is using your account**
> If you think someone is using your Google Account without your permission, follow the steps to [recover a hacked or hijacked Google Account or Gmail.](https://support.google.com/accounts?p=ar_haco)
>
> **Can’t sign in for another reason**
> If you have another problem, [get help signing in.](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620)